# How do you filter and replace list items in sharepoints using event receivers?

Tags: list, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, event-receiver

I have 2 SharePoint lists in my site collection: One "Comments" list and one "Filter" list. I'd like to filter and replace items in the comments list using the items from the filter list.. for example, one item in the comments list is about to be added, say, "Lorem Ipsum foullanguage" and there is a "foulanguage" entry in the "Filter" list, I want the result to be the "Lorem Ipsum *******" once the list item has been added. How do I do that using event receivers in Visual Studio?

Im using SP13 and VS2012 btw.

thank you!

here's what I have so far:

```
        public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
        {
            string comment = "";
            string filter = "";

            using (SPWeb oWebSiteRoot = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb)
            {
                SPList commentsList = oWebSiteRoot.Lists["Comments"];
                SPListItemCollection commentItems = commentsList.Items;

                SPList filterList = oWebSiteRoot.Lists["Filter"];
                SPListItemCollection filterItems = filterList.Items;



                foreach (SPListItem item in commentItems)
                {
                    comment = item.ToString();

                    foreach (SPListItem item2 in filterItems)
                    {
                        filter = item2.ToString();

                        if (comment.Contains(filter))
                        {
                            string replace = "*******";
                            replace = item.ToString();

                        }

                    }

                }


            }

        }


        base.ItemAdded(properties);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb()

   DisableEventFiring();
   string commentItem = properties.AfterProperties["ColumnName"].ToString();

   foreach (SPListItem item in filterItem)
            {
                comment = item.ToString();                  

                    if (item.Contains(commentItem))
                    {
                        properties.ListItem["ColumnName"] = "Lorem Ipsum *"; 
                        properties.ListItem.Update();

                    }



            }
```

*there may be some error, use this as logic... I've not completely tested

*Use "Properties" dont use "Using(){}" clause in event reciever

Comment: How do I specify where is where is should get the ["Column Name"]? I use two separate lists for comments and filters